# External swf in some cases loads the swf but displays a blank screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have an SWF that is used to load another external swf depending on the gameID and the selected language. In most cases it works fine, the bar appears and when it becomes full the new game is loaded. But Ive received reports that for some people when the bar finishes loading the screen becomes just blank (always). For example: one of those reports was WinXP, IE8 and Flash Player v10 but it worked fine for me when I tried a PC with those specs.

Since the game loads it fires the event.complete and not IEerror so It doesn't even display the error. Ive tried to check the content for null to display error but the content is not null.

```
stop();

var lang = root.loaderInfo.parameters.lingua;
var phpSession = root.loaderInfo.parameters.sessionPHP;
var gameID = root.loaderInfo.parameters.gameID;

loadbar.visible = false;
titulo.visible=true;

loadingbarerror.visible = false

if (lang != "" && phpSession != "" && gameID != "")
{

    var holder:Loader = new Loader();

    holder.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onGameLoading, false, 0, true);
    holder.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onGameComplete, false, 0, true);
    holder.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onGameError);
    loadbar.visible = false;

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("jogos/"+gameID+".swflingua="+lang+"&sessionPHP="+phpSession);

    holder.load(request);
}
else
{
    loadingbarerror.visible = true;
    titulo.visible = false;
}




function onGameLoading(e:ProgressEvent):void
{   
    loadbar.visible = true;
    var totalload = e.target.bytesTotal;
    var currentload = e.target.bytesLoaded;
    loadbar.scaleX = currentload/totalload

}

function onGameComplete(e:Event):void 
{  
    if (holder.content != null)
    {
        addChild(holder.content)
    }
    else
    {
        loadingbarerror.visible = true;
        titulo.visible = false;
    }

    holder.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onGameLoading)
    holder.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onGameComplete);
    holder.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onGameError);
}

function onGameError(e:Event)
{
    loadingbarerror.visible = true;
    titulo.visible = false;

    holder.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onGameLoading)
    holder.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onGameComplete);
    holder.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onGameError);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to debug a scenario you can't reproduce.  Best to get some assistance from those affected if possible. This might be hard to get someone to do, but if I were to pursue this error, I'd try and have someone who is affected by this bug install a debug flash player and screen shot the error they see when the bug happens.  Its likely a runtime error, but users who have the standard player will see it fail silently.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Ive used UncaughtErrorEvent.UNCAUGHT_ERROR to display errors but none showed up.

Comment: If the end user does not have a debug player installed no errors will show up, and you've said you can't reproduce it on your own, so I wouldn't expect UncaughtErrorEvent to show you anything.  you need to have someone who is seeing the problem install a debug flash player and tell you what pops up in the error window when your swf loads only a white screen.

Comment: I realized that the computers with problems can't install the debug flash player because they have no admin privileges. Maybe its something to do with URLRequest not having permission to obtain a file from the server?